# Python: Converting datetime.datetime to DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Trying to write some data to a database (InfluxDB) using the DataFrameClient, but apparently my timestamps don't have the right format:

```
DataFrameClient.write_points(json_body, measurement=Obj.project_handle, protocol='json')

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/_dataframe_client.py", line 131, in write_points
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/influxdb/_dataframe_client.py", line 230, in _convert_dataframe_to_json
raise TypeError('Must be DataFrame with DatetimeIndex or '
TypeError: Must be DataFrame with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex.
```

Looks like I have to convert the timestamps to DatetimeIndex format... I am attempting this with `pd.DatetimeIndex(datetime_index)`, getting the error:

```
DatetimeIndex() must be called with a collection of some kind, datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 18, 18, 21, 39, 596050, tzinfo=<UTC>) was passed.
```

Comment: try `df.set_index(datetime_index, inplace=True)`, provided `datetime_index` is the column object containing your datetime index values.

Comment: datetime_index is a single index